# mysql merging two triggers

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to make this trigger work for the two columns I have in my table, can anyone help me? MariaDB only supports one trigger per  table.

```
begin
    if (select count(*) from reservation where res_room = new.res_room) > 3 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    END if;
END
```

---

This is my merge attempt:

```
begin
    if (select count(*) from reservation where res_room = new.res_room) > 3 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    if (select count(*) from reservation where res_time = new.res_time) > 8 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    END if;
END
```

---

Comment: I'm sorry about that.

Comment: What is your MariaDB version. Their docs claim: `Until MariaDB 10.2.3, a table could have only one trigger defined for each event/timing combination: for example, a table could only have one BEFORE INSERT trigger.`

Comment: Is this trigger on the same table (`reservation`) that you are querying?

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
BEGIN
    if (select count(*) from reservation where res_room = new.res_room) > 3 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    elseif (select count(*) from reservation where res_time = new.res_time) > 8 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    END if;
END
```

That is, you want `elseif`.